# Git, how do I remove files with funny characters in the path?

Tags: git

I have a file that I can't get rid of in git. How do I commit this?

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/1.1.x' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
deleted:    "../../src/Interlated\220CamsBundle/Services/ApplicationRank.php"
```

Comment: what characters are funny, can you be more clear about your issue?

Comment: \220 is funny - well not haha.

Comment: Did you try a `git add -u .`: that should record the deletion. Then commit, and clone that repo to check the file has been removed from the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
git add -u
git commit -m "your commit message"
git push
```

Comment: That got it - I tried git add -u "file" which failed. Not adverse side effects.